# Abbreviated label created in ArcGIS Pro not working in ArcGIS Online

Tags: arcgis-online, arcade

I've created a label dictionary to shorten a status type label from displaying "Access" to "A" or "No Access" to "N".
This works perfectly in ArcGIS Pro, but reverts to "Access" in the Online environment. Here it is in ArcGIS Pro.

[image]

Here's what happens in ArcGIS Online.

[image]

I've been trying all kinds of combinations of expressions to produce the effect with Arcade, and I'm not  getting it correct.
This is the starting point in the editor.

[image]

I've tried var, iif, when, and being I'm still learning syntax I'm not getting anywhere.

Comment: Please always include Arcade expressions as formatted text rather than pictures.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's the answer in the shortest possible way I could discern.

```
var accessStatus = $feature["Access_Status"]
When(accessStatus == 'Access', "A",
     accessStatus == 'No Access', "N",
     accessStatus == 'Do NOT use this gate', "X",
     null)
```

Resource that got me over the edge is here.
“ArcGIS Online: Enrich Your Maps with Arcade”
https://youtu.be/Dmv_meDq07M

This got the job done.